# web2py: module function that behaves normally in shell fails browser mode

Tags: function, python-2.7, web2py

I have a very simple helper function that helps creates column definitions for a javascript framework I"m using.

```
def tocol(fields,title=None,width=None,attributes=None):
    cols = dict((name,eval(name)) for name in ['title','width','attributes'] if eval(name) is not None)
    cols["field"] = fields
    return cols
```

when I try this in a web2py shell the result is as I'd expect:

```
In [15]: col = tocol(attr.columns.tolist())
In [16]: col
Out[16]: {'field': ['l1', 'pw', 'bw', 'tilt']}
```

but when I try the same thing in a view I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tahnoon/web2py/gluon/restricted.py", line 224, in restricted
    exec ccode in environment
  File "/home/tahnoon/web2py/applications/apollo/controllers/performance.py", line 788, in <module>
  File "/home/tahnoon/web2py/gluon/globals.py", line 392, in <lambda>
    self._caller = lambda f: f()
  File "/home/tahnoon/web2py/applications/apollo/controllers/performance.py", line 561, in pa_equity
    cols = tocol(attr.columns.tolist())
  File "applications/apollo/modules/helpers.py", line 33, in tocol
    cols = dict((name,eval(name)) for name in ['title','width','attributes'] if eval(name) is not None)
  File "applications/apollo/modules/helpers.py", line 33, in <genexpr>
    cols = dict((name,eval(name)) for name in ['title','width','attributes'] if eval(name) is not None)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'title' is not defined
```

Might anyone have any idea what is going wrong here? Pretty mystified.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're just trying to remove `None` values from a dictionary, so instead, why not just create a function to do that:

```
def remove_none(d):
    [d.pop(key) for key in d.keys() if d[key] is None]
```

Then you can do:

```
col = remove_none(dict(field=attr.columns.tolist(),
                       title=None, width=None, attributes=None))
```

Or if you want to enter the arguments directly::

```
def remove_none_dict(**d):
    [d.pop(key) for key in d.keys() if d[key] is None]
    return d

col = remove_none_dict(field=attr.columns.tolist(),
                       title=None, width=None, attributes=None))
```

Comment: Thanks @Anthony. Makes perfect sense. Do you have a sense of what might be causing the behaviour though? Just a bit curious.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem, so hard to say without seeing more context.